# Selecting and playing movie from jit.playlist

Tags: selection, playlist, max-msp-jitter

I am trying to select a movie from a jit.playlist and play that movie on a specific midi note and another video on another note etc. I am using the ‘selection’ message to try and select a clip but can’t currently get it to work. Any idea what I might be doing wrong, or any other ways to select a specific movie and play it from a jit.playlist.

Comment: Hey Ben, could you paste a patch of what you have now? (Select all and choose Copy Compressed)

Answer (score 0):

We have to see your patch please, because we can't know what you might be doing wrong.

What you are asking is pretty simple if I have understood well enough your question. Here is a pseudo patch:

notein -> sel ( put your desired midi notes) -> the number of the jit.playlist video file

If that's what you want the patching is pretty easy but let me know if I got it right.

p.s: I would't recommend using the jit.playlist object. I have encountered numerous bugs.